# What percentage of Android phones are little-endian?

Tags: java, android, cpu-architecture, endianness

**edit:** This is different from *Endianness of Android NDK* because that question asks how to find the endianness, not how many devices are big/little-endian. Mods, please don't mark this as a dupe.

---

Just curious, is it worthwhile to support both big/little-endian Android phones? I have some code in my app that's endian-sensitive, for those of you who are curious it involves serializing a `long` to a byte stream. I think my phone is big-endian because `ByteBuffer.getLong()` is reading in a big-endian fashion from the byte stream I've written to.

Is it worthwhile to support big/little-endian Android phones? I'm not sure how common big-endian is compared to little-endian. Is there data available that tells us the relative percentages of each?

Thanks.

Comment: Android devices are (almost) entirely little endian at a native level, although Java is not. Not really an issue if you're careful. I say almost because I don't have a concrete source on hand, but I've never seen a Big Endian production device in 6 years of Android dev so far

Comment: I think according to this [article](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9451284) the Big-Endian is dead and as you can see in the link page the (machines are dual endian, but all the new OSs are littl endian only), which means you shouldn't curious about big endian.

Comment: @worker_bee That question asks how to test the endianness, not how many devices are big/little endian.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Android is always little-endian. This is documented on its page for [ABIs (Application Binary Interfaces)](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html):

> - The endianness of memory stores and loads at runtime. Android is always little-endian.

Comment: 2020 update: mips/mips64 is no longer supported by the Android NDK, and the ABI link above now explicitly says, "Android is always little-endian."

Comment: @jcgoble3 That certainly shortens my answer! Thank you for the update. (And sorry it took me several years to incorporate it!)